# 'click' doesn't switch to other option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to be able to click the 'beach' icon to play the appropriate svg image, mp3 song and mp4 video.
I've gone through look for any typos, missing capitalization, incorrect indentions, etc but I'm not seeing anything that could be the issue. Nothing is showing as an error in Visual Studio.

The section of code I believe the issue is located in; this is what is supposed to allow it to play the other song based on a click event.

```js
 //pick different sound(S)

    sounds.forEach(sound =>{
        sound.addEventListener('click', function(){
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-sound');
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-video');
            checkPlaying(song);
        });
    });
```

This is the full javascript

```js
const app = () => {
    const song = document.querySelector('.song');
    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    const outline = document.querySelector('.moving-outline circle');
    const video = document.querySelector('.vid-container video');

    //sounds
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll('.sound-picker button');
    //time display = h3 - html
    const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('.time-display');
    const timeselect = document.querySelectorAll('.time-select button');
    //Get the length of the outline
    const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
    //Duration
    let fakeDuration = 600;

    outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength; 
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

    //pick different sound(S)

    sounds.forEach(sound =>{
        sound.addEventListener('click', function(){
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-sound');
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-video');
            checkPlaying(song);
        });
    });

//Play Sound
    play.addEventListener("click", () => {
        checkPlaying(song);
    });

//Select sound
timeselect.forEach(option => {
option.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fakeDuration = this.getAttribute("data-time");
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60)}:${Math.floor(
        fakeDuration % 60
        )}`;
    });
});

// A function to stop and play the sounds
const checkPlaying = song => {
    if(song.paused) {
        song.play();
        video.play();
        play.src= "./svg/pause.svg";
    }   else{
            song.pause();
            video.pause();
            play.src = "./svg/play.svg";
    }
};

// Animate the circle
song.ontimeupdate = () => {
    let currentTime = song.currentTime;
    let elapsed = fakeDuration - currentTime;
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);

    //Animate the circle
    let progress = outlineLength - (currentTime / fakeDuration) * outlineLength;
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = progress;
    //Animate the text
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    if (currentTime >= fakeDuration) {
        song.pause();
        song.currentTime = 0;
        play.src = "./svg/play.svg";
        video.pause();
    }
  };
};

app();
```

The HTML code (where button data-sound and button data-video are located)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"></link>
    <title> Meditation App </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">

        <div class="vid-container">
            <video loop>
                <source src="./video/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="5"> 2 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="300"> 5 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="600"> 10 minutes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="player-container">
          <audio class="song">
                <source src="./sounds/rain.mp3"/>
            </audio>
            <img src="./svg/play.svg" alt="Play" class="play">
            <svg 
            class="track-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          
        <circle
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="white" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
        <svg 
        class="moving-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
        
        <circle 
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="#018EBA" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
        <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sound-picker">
            <button data-sound="./sounds/rain.mp3" data-video="./video/rain.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/rain.svg" alt="rain">
            </button>
            <button data-sound="./sounds/beach.mp3" data-video="./video/beach.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/beach.svg" alt="beach">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Css

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.time-select,
.sound-picker,
.player-container{
  height: 80%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-container{
  position: relative;
}

.player-container svg{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.time-display{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

video{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.time-select button,
.sound-picker button{
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.time-select button:hover{
  color: black;
  background: White;
}

.sound-picker button{
  border: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}


.sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
  background: #4972a1;
}
.sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
  background: #a14f49;
}

.sound-picker button img{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Any and all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: *"svg video"* you mean mp4 video?..

Comment: why are you assigning both video and audio urls to the song element?
here
`song.src = this.getAttribute('data-sound');song.src = this.getAttribute('data-video');`

Comment: @ZIASH it's supposed to play a specific background video loop with the specific song(s).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that's my mistake it is a .mp4

Comment: I think you should assign the `data-video` to the video elements src no the song element

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what's that you're building?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm following a video and can't locate the issue I've run into. https://youtu.be/oMBXdZzYqEk?t=2549   I've got everything else working thus far. no errors and I've re-read the section I'm at several times with no luck in spotting a difference.

Comment: @ZIASH I'm new to html/css/js and am following a video. This is how they did it in the video so it should work but I'll certainly look up a document on video element src for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are assigning a video to and audio element which is not supported

Check the sample I have provided, you can run the code and test it:

```js
const app = () => {
    const song = document.querySelector('.song');
    const play = document.querySelector('.play');
    const outline = document.querySelector('.moving-outline circle');
    const video = document.querySelector('.vid-container video');

    //sounds
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll('.sound-picker button');
    //time display = h3 - html
    const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('.time-display');
    const timeselect = document.querySelectorAll('.time-select button');
    //Get the length of the outline
    const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
    //Duration
    let fakeDuration = 600;

    outline.style.strokeDasharray = outlineLength; 
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = outlineLength;

    //pick different sound(S)

    sounds.forEach(sound =>{
        sound.addEventListener('click', function(){
            song.src = this.getAttribute('data-sound');
            video.src = this.getAttribute('data-video');
            checkPlaying(song);
        });
    });

//Play Sound
    play.addEventListener("click", () => {
        checkPlaying(song);
    });

//Select sound
timeselect.forEach(option => {
option.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fakeDuration = this.getAttribute("data-time");
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60)}:${Math.floor(
        fakeDuration % 60
        )}`;
    });
});

// A function to stop and play the sounds
const checkPlaying = song => {
    if(song.paused) {
        song.play();
        video.play();
        play.src= "./svg/pause.svg";
    }   else{
            song.pause();
            video.pause();
            play.src = "./svg/play.svg";
    }
};

// Animate the circle
song.ontimeupdate = () => {
    let currentTime = song.currentTime;
    let elapsed = fakeDuration - currentTime;
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);

    //Animate the circle
    let progress = outlineLength - (currentTime / fakeDuration) * outlineLength;
    outline.style.strokeDashoffset = progress;
    //Animate the text
    timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    if (currentTime >= fakeDuration) {
        song.pause();
        song.currentTime = 0;
        play.src = "./svg/play.svg";
        video.pause();
    }
  };
};

app();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.time-select,
.sound-picker,
.player-container{
  height: 80%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.player-container{
  position: relative;
}

.player-container svg{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.time-display{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

video{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}

.time-select button,
.sound-picker button{
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.time-select button:hover{
  color: black;
  background: White;
}

.sound-picker button{
  border: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}


.sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
  background: #4972a1;
}
.sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
  background: #a14f49;
}

.sound-picker button img{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"></link>
    <title> Meditation App </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">

        <div class="vid-container">
            <video loop>
                <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_5mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="5"> 2 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="300"> 5 minutes</button>
            <button data-time="600"> 10 minutes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="player-container">
          <audio class="song">
                <source src="https://assets.mixkit.co/active_storage/sfx/1714/1714-preview.mp3"/>
            </audio>
            <img src="./svg/play.svg" alt="Play" class="play">
            <svg 
            class="track-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          
        <circle
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="white" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
        <svg 
        class="moving-outline"
            width="453" 
            height="453" 
            viewBox="0 0 453 453" 
            fill="none" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
        
        <circle 
            cx="226.5" 
            cy="226.5" 
            r="216.5" 
            stroke="#018EBA" 
            stroke-width="20"
            />
        </svg>
        <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sound-picker">
            <button data-sound="https://assets.mixkit.co/active_storage/sfx/39/39-preview.mp3" data-video="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/rain.svg" alt="rain">
            </button>
            <button data-sound="https://assets.mixkit.co/active_storage/sfx/667/667-preview.mp3" data-video="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_5mb.mp4">
                <img src="./svg/beach.svg" alt="beach">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that worked; I went back and looked at the video to see and I believe the reason it didn't look different is because the person typed song.src for the video and went back later and changed it before running it.